# Progress bar component not showing up within Group/Stack

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, mantine

Whenever I try to place a progress bar inside a Group/Stack, it does not show up on my webpage. It works only when I place it outside the Group/Stack. Here is the code and results:

```
import { Stack, ThemeIcon, Text, Progress, Group, Button } from "@mantine/core";

interface SkillProps {
  name: string;
  icon: JSX.Element;
}

function Skill(props: SkillProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Group>
        <ThemeIcon size={50} radius={25} variant="outline">
          {props.icon}
        </ThemeIcon>

        <Stack align="center" spacing={5}>
          <Text>{props.name}</Text>
        </Stack>

        <Progress value={50} />
      </Group>
    </>
  );
}

export default Skill;
```

When placed within Group/Stack: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NquWu.png)

When placed outside Group/Stack: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji8nW.png)

Anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this might be because `Progress` does not have a specified width from parent container when in `Group` or `Stack`.

For use in `Group`, try add [`flex:"1"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to `Progress` with the [`sx` prop](https://mantine.dev/styles/sx/), which will make it take the remaining space in `Group`:

```
<Group>
  <ThemeIcon size={50} radius={25} variant="outline">
    {props.icon}
  </ThemeIcon>
  <Stack align="center" spacing={5}>
    <Text>{props.name}</Text>
  </Stack>
  <Progress value={20} sx={{ flex: "1" }} />
</Group>
```

For use in `Stack`, try add [`alignSelf: "stretch"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) instead for similar result:

```
<Group>
  <ThemeIcon size={50} radius={25} variant="outline">
    {props.icon}
  </ThemeIcon>
  <Stack align="center" spacing={5}>
    <Text>{props.name}</Text>
    <Progress value={20} sx={{ alignSelf: "stretch" }} />
  </Stack>
</Group>
```